# Swift 3 Core Data creating empty import

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3

When I create a NSManagedObject subclasses I get two files from each Entity. Why the properties file one is always creating an empty import?

For example: 
I create Aula Entity and below import CoreData there is an empty import... for what?

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import 

extension Aula {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Aula> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Aula>(entityName: "Aula");
    }

    @NSManaged public var data: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var conteudoProgramado: String?
    @NSManaged public var conteudoExecutado: String?
    @NSManaged public var turmas: Turma?

}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by empty import?

Comment: I edited the post and put an example!

Comment: I can't make that happen. Are you on the released version of Xcode 8 or still using one of the betas?